# Why isn't dragstart event firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/2m9Va/2/)

## code:

```
$(document).on('dragstart',function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});​
```

I thought `dragstart` and `dragstop` were supported events in newer browsers?

The `dragover` event fires just fine, but I want to show/hide a `<div>` when a user starts dragging a *file only*.

Testing in Chrome 23 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`dragenter` and `dragleave` fire, but only once you drag the file over top of the document, not as soon as you start dragging it from your OS. This is probably a security thing, so it will have to do.

```
$(document).on('dragenter', function(e) {
    $drop_files_msg.show();
});
$(document).on('dragleave', function(e) {
    $drop_files_msg.hide();
});
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as I assumed your file was something part of your page not an external file in the OS. In that case it makes no sense for the document to trigger the `dragstart` event if the drag is not started anywhere on the document and the code you have in your answer is the natural way of detecting when something is dragged over the document alright.